# Why is there a huge gap between these HTML SVG shapes?

Tags: html, svg, whitespace

These shapes all display properly, but for some reason there is a HUGE vertical gap of like 10,000px  between the first 2 shapes and the remaining shapes. When I open the page I have to scroll down a lot of white space to see the rest of the shapes.  I have not been able to figure out what is causing that.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>

<svg width="2000" height="2000">
       <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="green" />
    </svg>

<svg width="2000" height="2000">
       <rect cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="blue" />
    </svg>
<!-- THERE IS A WEIRD GAP HERE -->
<!-- SVG Rounded Rectangle
    Example -->
<svg width="400" height="180">
      <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150"
      style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
    </svg>
<!-- SVG Star
    Example -->
<svg width="300" height="200">
      <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
      style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
    </svg>
<!-- SVG Logo
    Example -->
<svg height="130" width="500">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
      <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">SVG</text>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
```

Comment: Did you notice `<svg width="2000" height="2000">` ?

Comment: I just caught that, ugh. Thanks, considering just deleting the question.

Comment: Also your 3rd shape, the rect, needs dimensions, without it there is no blue the gap seems even bigger than 2000

Comment: Also, the cy for the green circle pushes it down further as it is aligned on that svg container. You could try `cy="0"`.